# Saving prefrences and accounts in Android app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an application which supports multiple accounts (max 8). These accounts are local to the app. Each account has the following parts

- Name of Site
- Site tel number
- type of control
- username
- pass

Currently I plan to implement them by using shared preferences. I will define keys for all the elements of 8 groups and save/retrieve them using shared preferences. I would like to know is this a good approach or should I use another approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use SQLite database for implementing your requirement. The main advantages of using this is 
1. Can check username and password in easy way. 

2. Can add more users in future.
[SQLite Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial)

Comment: Please can u provide an easy to learn and understand example for doing this using SQLIte?

Answer (score 2):

'SharedPreferences' are stored in the data directory for the app, but if the user has a rooted device, this file can easily be accessed and read with just a text editor.

For storing account information, you should look into using MySQLi and data encryption.

Answer (score 1):

As you have limited number of accounts and just a few settings for your accounts, that will work ok for you as you have up to 40 settings to save. It won't cause performance problems and you can write some kind helper class to manage those shared properties easier.

You should think about whether you want to increase the number of accounts in the future. If this is the case, you should consider SQLite database.